# JavaScript: call-by-name parameter evaluation

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function, which reports that some element was loaded:

```
var reportLoaded = function(element) {
    $("<div>" + element + " loaded " + new Date().getMilliseconds() 
              + "</div>").appendTo("body");
}
```

But when I attach this function to, for example, jQuery's `ready` method:

```
$(document).ready(reportLoaded("document"))
```

it's not working, because function is evaluated directly.

So I had to do something like this:

```
var reportLoadedDelayed = function(element) {
    return function() {
        reportLoaded(element);
    }   
}

$(document).ready(reportLoadedDelayed("document"))
```

Is there a short notation to specify that you want your parameters evaluated by name? Like in Scala you can declare a function:

```
def lazyEval(x: => Int) = {println("lazy"); x;}
```

and the x will be evaluated when it's actually needed, if at all.

Comment: You can use `$(document).ready( function(){ reportLoaded("document"); });`

Comment: Yes, but it's tedious to write it every time manually, so I thought there might be some syntactic sugar.

Comment: Well you can cut down on the typing by using `$(function() {})` instead of `$(document).ready(function() {})`...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I  was just typing a comment under your question, but you answered it here. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I attach this function to, for example, jQuery's ready method:
>
> `$(document).ready(reportLoaded("document"))`

That doesn't attach it to `ready`. It *calls* `reportLoaded("document")` and passes its *return value* into `ready`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` *calls* `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

If you want to actually pass a function reference in, use a function expression or [`Function#bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5), which can be used to curry arguments:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    reportLoaded("document");
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(reportLoaded.bind(null, "document"));
```

or actually, jQuery has [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
$(document).ready($.proxy(reportLoaded, null, "document"));
```

---

If you do this a lot, you can get rid of the need to type `null` all the time by giving yourself a `curry` function:

```
// Best to have this in a scoping function
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
Function.prototype.curry = function() {
    var args =  slice.call(arguments, 0);
    args.unshift(null);
    return this.bind.apply(this, args);
};
```

---

Note that `Function#bind` is "new" in ES5 (2009), but easily polyfilled if you need to support older browsers like IE8.

Comment: Is this `function expression` the same as an anonymous function which calls `reportLoaded`, or is this some kind of special JavaScript Syntax, that doesn't require 2 function invocations?

Comment: @maja: I don't understand the question. There's no "special" JavaScript syntax; there's just JavaScript syntax. One aspect of JavaScript syntax is that you can have function expressions, and they can be anonymous. The one above is anonymous. JavaScript also has *named* function expressions, and separately, function *declarations* (which always have to have names). Soon (ES6) it will have arrow function declarations as well.

Comment: My question is (or was), if the ready-event will first invoke the anonymous function and then the actual `reportLoaded`-function, or if the specification states that "in this case, only the inner function is invoked, and the anonymous function is discarded for performance reasons". (Ignoring the possibility of non-standard browser optimisations)

Comment: @maja: When we execute the `ready` line, only `ready` is actually executed. *Later*, when jQuery decides the DOM is ready, it will call the anonymous function, which will call `reportLoaded`. Of course, a JavaScript engine is free to optimize provided doing so doesn't have side effects that take it outside of spec, but that would be awkward here, and in general the spec doesn't (as of ES5) get into optimizations.

Comment: I'm trying to add a function to the function's prototype (just like you did in the example). Is it possible to get a reference to the function being prototyped? `this` doesn't work. I want to call `reportLoaded.lazy("document")` and get a wrapper automatically. It's just for fun, to understand js better.

Comment: @damluar: Given the call `reportLoaded.lazy("document")`, assuming you added `lazy` to `Function.prototype`, `this` within the call would indeed be the function.

Comment: @damluar: `this` is the function **within the call to `lazy`**. But your `lazy` function is returning a different function; `this` during the call to the other function will be whatever jQuery calls it with.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as lambda expressions in Javascript, the closest is a function expression:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ reportLoaded("document"); });
```

You can also use the [`proxy` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to create a function from the function identifier, and bind the parameter to it:

```
$(document).ready($.proxy(reportLoaded, this, "document"));
```